# carbon start of week sunday and endOfWeek Saturday not working

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I need to select a particular users weekly top score. I am using Carbon and I forced Carbon startofWeek to SUNDAY and endOfWeek to SATURDAY.

Here is my DB data

```
id  user_id score   created_at            updated_at
43  33      88      2020-02-23 00:00:00     NULL
44  33      15      2020-02-24 00:00:00     NULL
45  33      42      2020-02-24 00:00:00     NULL
46  33      86      2020-02-25 00:00:00     NULL
47  33      100     2020-02-04 00:00:00     NULL
```

Here is my code

```
     $week = GameScore::select(max('score')
             ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(Carbon::SUNDAY))
             ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfWeek(Carbon::SATURDAY))
             ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->get();
```

According to my data I need to get score 88 as result , because this score is obtained on 23rd Feb Sunday which is this weeks starting and till today all other scores are not greater than this.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you need to specify the date format when comparing,

```
Carbon::now()->endOfWeek(Carbon::SATURDAY)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: But according to my requirement I need to get a users weekly top score. So from above data I need to get 88 as the result. But I am getting only 86.

Answer (score 1):

```
$en = CarbonImmutable::now()->locale('en_US');


 $ar = CarbonImmutable::now()->locale('ar');



// We still can force to use an other day as start/end of week
   $start = $en->startOfWeek(Carbon::TUESDAY);
   $end = $en->endOfWeek(Carbon::SATURDAY);
```

var_dump($ar->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d H:i'));

Is working for me

Answer (score 1):

You can set the starting day of the week by using the Carbon static function `setWeekStartsAt` and also can use that to work out the end of week day.

```php
public static function getWeekStartAndEndDates($date, $startDayIndex = Carbon::SATURDAY)
    {
        $date = Carbon::parse($date);
        $date::setWeekStartsAt($startDayIndex);

        $from = $date->startOfWeek();

        $date::setWeekEndsAt($from->copy()->addDays(6)->dayOfWeek);
        $to = $date->copy()->endOfWeek();

        return ['from' => $from, 'to' => $to];
    }
```